# Word request for a situation

Tags: single-word-requests

Term for someone who is strong in a opinion/opinions of his but is open minded enough not to stress it on others and is adjustable in nature. For example a person may be very racist but on meeting strangers never shows even a slight inclination over his opinion
We can describe it as something like acting or faking but it seems a very general term
 I'm looking for a high-fi term

Comment: Start by considering synonyms for [**garded**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/guarded) *- cautious, careful, circumspect, wary, chary, reluctant, non-committal, reticent, restrained, reserved, controlled, moderate, discreet, unrevealing, vague, diplomatic, prudent, politic, tactful.*

Comment: From your initial description of this hypothetical person: "strong in a opinion/opinions of his but is open minded", "acting or faking" seems inconsistent.

Comment: I think you are describing two different characteristics - 'dogmatic', yet 'teachable', for example. These cannot be encapsulated within one word, in my view.

Comment: We need a sample sentence.

Comment: What is a "high-fi" term?

Comment: I don't think "open-minded" was itself one of the traits to be encapsulated here. It sounds like this person is just "open-minded enough" to understand that his strong views are perhaps outside the mainstream, and thus should best be kept under his hat. Perhaps a quick clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm at a loss to find one word that covers those requirements.

You describe I think at least two and possibly three separate character traits...

1st **thoughtful** (strongly opinionated)

2nd **private** (does not offer an opinion to strangers)

3rd or possibly part of the 1st trait: **open-minded** (adjustable)

Now, with regards to the "acting / faking". This to me sounds something like:

*Having a **[neutral expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blank_expression)**.*

There are other ways of describing it, "Poker Face" or Game Face", being 'opaque' or 'un-readable'.

*that* is a skill a person has to enable them to mask their feelings and responses.